# lein repl makes my Clojure source files readonly in Vim on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, clojure, leiningen

I don't know where the problem lies, but when I do `lein repl` or `lein vimclojure` in a project, and then open a Clojure source file from the same project in Vim, it's readonly, like it is being used or something. If I do `:set noreadonly`, `:set readonly?` answers `noreadonly`, but Vim still says that the file "is read-only" when I try to write it. I can write it with `:w!`, and nothing bad seems to happen. Does anyone have any idea of what could be wrong, or know of a work-around? I don't want the files to be readonly when I'm coding. I'm on Windows, by the way. When I open the files in notepad or Emacs, they are not readonly and I have no problem saving them. Even if I shut down the repl, and try to turn off `readonly` in Vim, Vim still doesn't let me save the files without `!`.

Just to be clear, if I don't start a repl first I have no problems whatsoever.

Comment: I guess we can drop "vim part" of the question :) Could you just check file permissions before and after `lein repl`?

Comment: What kind of permissions are you talking about? The security permissions do not change.

Comment: Ok. Did you check owner of vim process? Does this user have permissions to write the file?

Comment: Yes. If I don't start a repl first there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned the leiningen repo a few days ago (commit e01a1980af0b2cd07c56626f684b2f2ba50adf44 of 2012-12-29 was the last commit in my clone) to get a more recent version that fixed another issue I had, and I noticed that I do not have this problem with this new version.